# Group rows and don't displays number as a scientific notation

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using PHP to do this.
I have a table on my DB where one value can have two semi-similar records and I want to display them at the same row on HTML. No, I can't group in MySQL `select`, because I have only 2 or 3 (max 4) columns of this table with the SAME value and others columns have different values (frequencies, counts).
To be more understandable, I have a table where the column position can admit two records (or more) of the same position. Have three columns (example), calleds A, B and C, that have the same value (normally) for the same position and four columns (example), D, E, F and G with the differents values.

What I want?

On print the data on screen, I wanna group the values with the same position (and if the A, B, C or others columns of the same position have the same value, group this and displays only one time), but displays the two different values in the same row, one above the another.

I created a while, where:

```
Select all DB data
While with all data to list (fetch_array);
    Select the FK data;
    Select the repeated data from table with a where condition in position;
    IF the select of repeated data result have more than two rows:
        X
    Else
        Display the individual rows.
End of while.
```

What I can do in X is only displays with the different color... I can't sintetize the way to merge these rows with the same value... :S

To understand better...

My table actually:

```
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  Position     |   Variable         | Frequence      | Data
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  102230       | Information 1      | 0.0003         |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------  
  102230       | Information 2      | 0.00743        |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  103330       | Information x      | 0.002558       |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
 1033340       | Information y      | 0.00255        |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------  
  102220       | Information 4      | 0.0099553      |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------  
  102220       | Information 5      | 0.00722243     |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
```

What I want:

```
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  Position     |   Variable         | Frequence      | Data
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  102230       | Information 1      | 0.0003         |   A
               | Information 2      | 0.00743        |   
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
  103330       | Information x      | 0.002558       |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
 1033340       | Information y      | 0.00255        |   A
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------  
  102220       | Information 4      | 0.0099553      |   A
               | Information 5      | 0.00722243     |   
---------------|--------------------|----------------|----------------
```

This is an example of my table... I wanna merge the cells what in the repeated position, have the same value (it's the A cell and the position number, on this example - but on my real script, I have more columns), and displays these value one time. And the columns that have different values, but are from the same merged position, the values are displayed in the same row, but one below of the other.

And I have another issue. I have a decimal column with frequencies, but I can't determine the size of numbers after the dot, so I put a big size to data after the dot.

The problem?

The script prints numbers like this:

```
0.00000828700000000000
0.00216100000000000000
```

And I want this:

```
0.000008287
0.002161
```

But when I use the `floatval()`, the script returns:

```
8.287E-6
0.002161
```

And I don't want the return in scientific notation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **floatval()** you can use [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) and [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$number = rtrim(sprintf('%.20f', "0.00000828700000000000"), "0");
```

The output of previous line is: 0.000008287

Comment: Oh, thanks!
I used only this:

`rtrim("0.00000828700000000000", "0");`

and worked...